# Si es 1 = ON si es 0 = OFF y las demas variables quedar iguale

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
 <div className="size-boton mt-0  " style={{color:miscolores[i+4]}} >                                                    


      {(data.measurements[data.measurements.length-1].value === 1) ? "ON" : 
      (data.measurements[data.measurements.length-1].value)} 

</div>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

solo las 2 primeras variables cambian entre 0 y 1 lo que necesito es cuando sea 1 mostrar ON y cuando sea 0 OFF, alli esta mostrando ON porque esta en 1

Comment: en javascript existe `0,1,null,undefined` supongo que preguntas esto , pero aun no me queda clara

Comment: Lo siento. No es clara la pregunta ni lo que buscas.

Comment: Necesitamos un poco más de codigo. Por ejemplo: que hay dentro de tu variable `data` exactamente?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que puedes que hacer es controlar exactamente cuando ese valor es 1, 0 o el que quieras, y seguidamente mostrar lo que quieras cuando tu condición se cumpla. Te propongo algo así.

```
render () {
  const ON = data.measurements[data.measurements.length-1].value === 1;
  const OFF = data.measurements[data.measurements.length-1].value === 0;

  return (    
    <div className="size-boton mt-0  " style={{color:miscolores[i+4]}} >                                                    
      {ON && "ON"}
      {OFF && "OFF"}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: me sirvio gracias al final pude realizarlo asi

{(data.measurements[data.measurements.length-1].value === 0) && "OFF"}
                                                                                {(data.measurements[data.measurements.length-1].value === 1) && "ON"}
                                                                                {(data.measurements[data.measurements.length-1].value !== 0 &&  data.measurements[data.measurements.length-1].value !== 1) && data.measurements[data.measurements.length-1].value}